# ChromeDriver execution waiting at driver.get(url)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

My configuration as below:
Chrome - 65
Chromedriver exe - 2.67

My application throws up a credentials popup when I hit driver.get(url). I have used sikuli to enter the credentials on the chrome browser's credential popup.

Recently, we had an chrome 65 upgrade. Post this update, the execution stays blocked at line driver.get(url) until the credentials are entered manually on the popup. But, the sikuli code to handle the popup is on line next to driver.get(url).

Any workaround available, so that the execution comes out of line driver.get(url) inspite of the there being a popup so that my sikuli code can handle that?

Comment: one option came to my mind is that using multi-threading. Run driver.get and sikuli script in two threads and joining sikuli thread with the driver.get thread (which is main thread). so, when sikuli enters the credentials, it finishes its thread and release to main thread. now as credentials are entered, driver.get will continue with loading the page. This may be bit complicated. Other may have easier answers

Comment: Dit it work if you revert to chromedriver 2.36 ? Because according to [selenium driver doc](https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/) chromedriver needs to be in 2.36 version

Comment: Why don't you use webdriver api to handle the authentication dialog instead of using sikuli ? you can switch to the authentication alert and handle it using webdriver. For ex : In C# ,you can use  ` IAlert alert = WebDriver.SwitchTo().Alert();alert.SetAuthenticationCredentials(userName,Password)` .....Another, way is when you are navigating to the url, you can format the url as http://username:password@somesite.com...This will bypass authentication dialog..or simply move driver.get(url) call in your code after sikuli script is done entering credentials..

Answer (score 0):

Found solution for this , can be handled through thread concept ,

```
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
            driver.get(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }
    }, url);
    t.start();
```

// Next line of code :AutoIT or Robot or Sikuli to handle security pop-up